# how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe and in order to access parent element I implemented following code:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('parentPrice').innerHTML
```

How to get the same result using jquery?
**UPDATE**: Or how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114243/retrieving-a-documents-parent-iframe-in-jquery/36445098#36445098

Answer (score 526, accepted):

To find in the parent of the iFrame use:

```
$('#parentPrice', window.parent.document).html();
```

The second parameter for the $() wrapper is the context in which to search. This defaults to document.

Comment: Cool - you acknowledged the thanks before he thanked you.
StackOverflow having problems with timezones maybe?

Comment: You could also do: $(window.parent.document).find("#parentPrice").html();

Comment: @belugabob It's a wizzard's fault.

Comment: For those who launched a windoid with window.open, don't forget about that old JS standard window.opener.document.  $("#someDiv", window.opener.document) works.

Comment: What about `$("#someDiv", top.document)`?

Comment: This will only work if the source of the iframe has jQuery loaded. In my experience, the iframe source would not have jQuery but the need to call one of the parent's jQuery functions is often needed. To do this use: window.document.$("#parentPrice").html()   This was the answer Álvaro G. Vicario posted.

Comment: @jhorback One *should* be using that approach, as $("#node", context) internally calls find().

Answer (score 41):

> how to access iFrame parent page using jquery

window.parent.document.

jQuery is a library on top of JavaScript, not a complete replacement for it. You don't have to replace every last JavaScript expression with something involving $.

Comment: +1. jQuery is great, but lots of answers to simple problems seem to be 'use jQuery'. If you're loading the library anyway, fine, but don't load it one task. Also, people seem concerned about JS perf, then use an API on top of JS to do things easily possible (and possibly faster) without the API.

Comment: @Grant Though I do dream of jQuery becoming native code inside browsers.

Comment: @Blowski: that's my nightmare! jQuery contains a lot of extremely complex and fragile “do what I mean” code that would be completely inappropriate to put in an official API.

Comment: @Blowski, I'd like to join your oppinion, however, even jQuery has its own shortcomings. In addition it is evolving and evolving much faster than any other JS lib. So it will be very difficult for js engines to keep up to date )).

Comment: @bobince: Clearly, you should _always_ replace all Javascript with jQuery. It's like bacon; there is no situation in which less is better. ;)

Comment: The OP already had window.parent.document, so this didn't answer anything.  And imagine the selector logic being a lot more complex than an element's ID, a situation in which jQuery is darn handy.  I feel like the question is "how do I say 'hello' in French?" and this answer is "speak German".

Comment: No, it's a bit more like saying, "You don't need to learn French! This is Germany! German is fine." With a little yelling and hand-waving for effect. :-)

Answer (score 15):

If you need to find the jQuery instance in the parent document (e.g., to call an utility function provided by a plug-in) use one of these syntaxes:

- `window.parent.$`
- `window.parent.jQuery`

Example:

```
window.parent.$.modal.close();
```

jQuery gets attached to the `window` object and that's what `window.parent` is.

Comment: I'm using my iframe like a user control. This lets me keep it nice and clean.

Answer (score 14):

You can access elements of parent window from within an iframe by using [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/parent) like this:

```
// using jquery    
window.parent.$("#element_id");
```

Which is the same as:

```
// pure javascript
window.parent.document.getElementById("element_id");
```

And if you have more than one nested iframes and you want to access the topmost iframe, then you can use [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) like this:

```
// using jquery
window.top.$("#element_id");
```

Which is the same as:

```
// pure javascript
window.top.document.getElementById("element_id");
```

Answer (score 7):

in parent window put :

```
<script>
function ifDoneChildFrame(val)
{
   $('#parentPrice').html(val);
}
</script>
```

and in iframe src file put :

```
<script>window.parent.ifDoneChildFrame('Your value here');</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

yeah it works for me as well.

Note : we need to use window.parent.document

```
    $("button", window.parent.document).click(function()
    {
        alert("Functionality defined by def");
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

It's working for me with little twist. 
In my case I have to populate value from POPUP JS to PARENT WINDOW form.

So I have used `$('#ee_id',window.opener.document).val(eeID);`

Excellent!!!

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little late to the game here, but I just discovered this fantastic jQuery plugin https://github.com/mkdynamic/jquery-popupwindow. It basically uses an onUnload callback event, so it basically listens out for the closing of the child window, and will perform any necessary stuff at that point. SO there's really no need to write any JS in the child window to pass back to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do these.

I) Get main parent directly.

for exa. i want to replace my child page to iframe then

```
var link = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Home/SubscribeReport")%>';
top.location.replace(link);
```

here **top.location** gets parent directly.

II) get parent one by one,

```
var element = $('.iframe:visible', window.parent.document);
```

here if you have more then one iframe, then specify active or visible one.

you also can do like these for getting further parents,

```
var masterParent = element.parent().parent().parent()
```

III) get parent by Identifier.

```
var myWindow = window.top.$("#Identifier")
```