# passing variable back to parent when fancybox window is closed

Tags: jquery, variables, fancybox, parent

I was wondering if it is possible to pass back a variable from fancybox child to parent once child is closed?

```
function cleanUp(){
    var bla = $("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('input[name=pd_id]');
    alert(bla.val());
}
$("#tree .product a[class!=copy]").fancybox({
    'width'             : 770,
    'height'            : '95%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'onCleanup'         : cleanUp
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the [fancybox api](http://fancybox.net/api) : `onClosed... Will be called once FancyBox is closed`

```
$('.overlay').fancybox({
    onClosed: function() { 
        var bla = $('#targetFrame')[0].contentWindow.targetFunction(); 
    }
});
```

There is no child window/iframe, the box is simply an absolutely positioned div. It's in the same DOM as the page.

Comment: I understand what you have put but that is simply letting me do something or calling a function onclose/cleanup/open... it's not actualy getting a varibal from the child window. And using it within the parent. Im looking to pass a variable back from the child.

Comment: Not sure what the jQuery equivalent is but you can use .contentWindow to access the iframe. See my edit above.

Comment: Hi thanks after the first edit did not work I skipped calling the function altogether and accesed the DOM for my var cheers (my solution is in my orig question).

Comment: I thought you were trying to access a javascript variable. A little context (html source) would have helped. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: I had the same problem and the `fancybox-frame` selector was turning up nothing. Here's what worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice

Comment: in case anyone is using Fancybox 2, it changed the function from `onClosed` to `afterClose`.

Answer (score 5):

In the parent, I define

```
var $_returnvalue = false;
```

And onClosed looks like this:

```
onClosed: function() {
    if ($_returnvalue != false)
    {
        // Do something in the parent
    }
```

And in the fancybox page, when something is ready to be returned, I set that value to **parent.$_returnvalue** and then close the box.  This works well for selecting something from a list and passing that value back to the calling page.

Comment: works well. In case anyone is using Fancybox 2, it changed the function from `onClosed` to `afterClose`.