# Access DOM objects of parent window from jQuery DOMWindow loaded with iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I have a web-page with a jQuery DOMWindow that loads its content from an iFrame. I need to access elements of the parent window from the iFrame. Is this possible?

This is the configuration for the DOMWindow that is opened from my main page:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.AjaxDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
                anchoredClassName:'DOMWindow',
                draggable: 1,
                eventType:'click',
                height:500,
                loader:1,
                loaderHeight:16,
                loaderImagePath:'/js/jquery/DOMWindow/animationProcessing.gif',
                loaderWidth:17,
                positionLeft:0,
                positionTop:0,
                positionType:'centered',
                width:700,
                windowSource:'iframe'
            });
```

I'm attempting to access the parent window's elements from the DOM box with:

```
parent.document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '';
```

But this doesn't appear to work. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate. Thank you for the suggestion. The above question doesn't refer to an iframe loaded inside of a DOMWindow - which is my scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
parent.document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '';
```

to

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 5):

I see you have **[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)** as tag so you can do this as below.

```
$( "#foo", window.opener.document)
```

**OR**

```
window.opener.document.$("#foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work :

```
$(window.parent.document).find("#foo")
```