# JQuery Window.Opener

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener

twoI am trying to write back some values to a parent page and have written the following but it is saying that SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined

```
$('#Save').click(function () {
    var parent = $(parent.document.body);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_address1').val(addone);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_address2').val(addtwo);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_city').val(city);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_county').val(county);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_postcode').val(postcode);
    $(parent).find('input#addr_country').val(country);
    window.close();            
});
```

Essentially the variables are set in another function and the values need to be sent back to a set of fields on the parent page.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `$("#input#addr_address1", window.parent.document);` should work, as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice).

Comment: @szajmon thats great thanks however the fields in the parent are not being populated

Comment: you have some clarity issues in the above code.  you're setting _address2 to addone, for example, and double-jquerifying `parent`...

Answer (score 1):

In the F12 debugger (I assume you're using IE, by the format of the error message), check the values of `parent` and `parent.document`.  I bet `parent` is null.  did you mean `opener`? or `top`?

Comment: I am trying to parse the selected values back to the source screen and populate some fields there

Comment: when you put a breakpoint on the line reading `var parent = $(parent.document.body);`, and then hover your mouse over `parent` in the source, what value do you see? if it is null, that is your problem.