# Getting parents document from iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I have seen some elegant solutions on fetching the parents document from iframe - like e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice/726866#726866). However, I can't make it work - and I didn't think this was possible due to securities issues (cross domain scripting?)?

My question is; can I still access the parents document from inside an iframe - or has this changed the recent years? If I should be able to access this; any thoughts on why I get undefined when printing `parent.document` or `window.parent.document` from the content of the iframe?

Comment: `window.top` generally works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's still possible to access the parent from within a frame **provided that the domains match**.

For example, have a look at these fiddles:

- Frame host: `fiddle.jshell.net`, parent host: `fiddle.net` **Does not match = failure**
   Test #1: http://jsfiddle.net/nrRQg/1/
- Frame host: `jsfiddle.net`, parent host: `jsfiddle.net` **Matches = success*
  Test #2: http://jsfiddle.net/nrRQg/1/show/

You can access the parent through:

```
window.parent
parent
top          //If the parent is the top-level document
window.top
```

The variables `parent` and `top` can be overwritten (usually not intended). It's safer to use `window.parent` to be more safe. Alternatively, you can replace `window` by `document.defaultView`.

Comment: Thx! The domains doesn't match, so that's obviously a problem. Now that you say it I know that I've read about this a while back. When the domains don't match you can't access the parents document. So my problem can't be solved when the framed content is on different domains. Right?

Comment: There are some tricks to still communicate across different domains. Have a look at [this lengthy article](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes). If both pages are served at the same domain, but with a different subdomain, setting the [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain) will help. Otherwise, if you are the owner of both websites, you can implement [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).