# window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, html, meta

var metaTags = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
console.log("hello"+metaTags.length);

My script is running in an iframe and I am not able to access the parent documents meta tags.The funning thing is nothing is getting printed on console.Not even Hellonull or something.

Thanks in advance
Swaraj

Comment: are the iframe and its parent in the same domain?

Comment: @PraveenB document.URL and window.parent.document.URL give out same URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you cannot execute cross frames/domains. If the domains match, you can do this, but if not, then it is a security issue that blocks it.  Here is an example of doing so when the domains are the same: [Getting parents document from iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8066547)

Comment: document.URL and window.parent.document.URL give out same URL