# ajax sub page to communicate back to the parent page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

i have a parent page that calls a sub page in a div.

the parent page has a text box

```
<input name="txtTicketNo" placeholder="Ticket #"  type="text" value="" class="textbox" readonly="readonly" id="txtTicketNo">
```

when the child page is called it queries the DB and gets the new record ID which lets says is 1271.  so in the child page my code piece looks like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sub_tIDi" id="sub_tIDi" value="<%=oRs(0)%>">
```

Now i want this 1271 to be written into txtTicketNo in the parent page.

This is what i have tried.

```
var stID;
stID = document.getElementById('sub_tIDi');
opener.document.NewTicket.txtTicketNo.value = stID.value;
```

the code runs without error, but there is no value in the text box of the parent page.

appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: When you say sub page do you mean in an `<iframe>`? Then you want to look at referencing the parent something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8066689/692942).

Comment: no iFrame i have just <Div>

Comment: A `<div>` in the page is just another element the fact you use it like a popup doesn't mean it will behave like one `opener` will not work here. Just give your `<div>` an `id` then use `getElementById()` to reference it. The fact you talk about *"parent page"* and *"sub page*" is misleading.

Comment: Sorry notice your using [tag:jquery] so try something like this `$("#divid").find("input[name=sub_tIDi]").val();`.

Comment: well i tried with removing the opener word and just used document.NewTicket.txtTicketNo.value = stID.value; and no good.

Comment: If you don't want to use [tag:jquery] and your `sub_tIDi` is the only element with that `name` in the page you should be able to use `document.getElementsByName("sub_tIDi")[0].value`.

Comment: the sub-Page("that is the page that gets AJAX called") does not have any <div> but has a table with id=ShowDataTable