# How to access html elements in iframe inside html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a html file which contains iframe like below lines of code. Note that this iframe is displayed by one of tiny mce jquery and is rendered in browser as
below

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <textarea id="texteditor"></textarea>
   <div class="mceeditor">
     <iframe>
       <html>
         <body>
           <script type="text/javascript">

     function mySubmit() {
         var URL = "http://localhost:61222/14CommunityImages/hands.png";

         window.document.getElementById("texteditor").value = URL;
               }
          </script>
          </body>
       </html>  
     </iframe>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Now my goal is to append var url inside text area which is in parent html tag.
Please help me !!!

Comment: move the script out of the iframe and into the parent page, then just select the nodes.

Comment: it cannot be moved as it is displayed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The document in the `iframe` can access its parent window via `parent`, and its parent window's document via `parent.document`. So:

```
parent.document.getElementById("texteditor").value = URL;
```

**Note:** To access each-other's documents, the main document and the iframe must be on the [*same origin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If they're on *different* origins, they can still communicate, but only if they **both** do so expressly, via [web messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/).

---

Side note: Your `iframe`, as shown in the question, won't work. Inline content in iframes is for display when the browser doesn't support iframes. You use a *separate* resource (e.g., page) identified by the `src` attribute (or you use the `srcdoc` attribute; I have no idea how well supported it is), for the iframe's content.

E.g.:

Main page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main Page</title>
<body>
<textarea id="texteditor"></textarea>
<div class="mceeditor">
    <iframe src="theframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`theframe.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Click to set" onclick="mySubmit()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mySubmit() {
            var URL = "http://localhost:61222/14CommunityImages/hands.png";

            parent.document.getElementById("texteditor").value = URL;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still worth noting that reverse access is not permitted, you cannot access iframe document from parent document.

Comment: @evc: You can if they're on the same origin.

Comment: Oh, didn't know, thanks!, Also found this great [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066547/getting-parents-document-from-iframe)

Comment: @user2179026: It works fine. If it's not working, there's something going on you haven't mentioned in the question.