# How to get element from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have iframe and in the iframe i need to get element of the parent window. How can i do it ?

```
    index.html
```

child.html
get parent element by id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting parents document from iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066547/getting-parents-document-from-iframe) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe

Answer (score 1):

If you have `var myVar` in the parent window, you can access it from the child window with `window.parent.myVar`.

Note: this will only work if both child and parent are on the same domain.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) for more info.