# How to do an action when iframe is generated and loaded dynamically from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I a developing a site where I am using grails as my backend and php as my frontend and datatypes returns as JSON and Jquery. The issue is when I submit my form to target an iframe its work fine and return true value but
yes on submitting the from I generates the iframe using jquery

**Now what I have to do is take value out of that iframe and used it in my parent webpage and also to reset the form after submitting and iframe loaded how can I achieve this and how can I use jquery events on this.**

What event should I use to generate effects on my page after the data is posted successfully and hidden iframe loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around I found sound help on Stack Overflow, about how to access iFrame parent page using jQuery.

```
window.parent.document
```

jQuery is a library on top of JavaScript, not a complete replacement for it. You don't have to replace every last JavaScript expression with something involving `$`.

To find in the parent of the iFrame use:

```
$('#parentPrice', window.parent.document).html();
```

[how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice)