# How to close an iframe with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this element on the page:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" id="fa-iframe" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" style="height: 513px; width: 597px; "></iframe>
```

Now, I run jquery within it and try to close it...

The jquery should execute some function on the element...

I tried solutions such as this..but it didnt work:

```
document.getElementById('fa-iframe').style.display="none";
```

How do I close the iframe..while the document with the javascript is inside the iframe?

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice

Answer (score 2):

You need to manipulate the DOM of the parent window (`parent`). This is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).