# Accessing data from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we have the following structure :

```
  <div id='main'>
   <div id="1"> .. </div>
   <div id="2">
     <iframe id="ifr" src="some"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
```

How can we access div#1 contents from inside the iframe#ifr?

Comment: You should [try the search once in a while](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+iframe)

Comment: Here is the answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :)

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('1')
```

Comment: or just `document.getElementById(theElName)`