# Select iframe parent from within iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe which does picture uploading to give a false sense of Ajax uploading.

This iframe's content has javascript which checks various things and sends status. See it as a progress report almost. Anyway, my page that contains the iframe, is the one showing the data and what not, so I want to change the data on the parent page, from within the iframe. Here is my code:

```
<div id="iframe_response"></div>
<iframe style="border:none" src="someurl" width="100%" height="350px" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

And here is my jQuery in the iframe:

```
$('#iframe_response', "#iframe").append('this should go there but it\'s not...');
```

It does however not write anything to that div. I have called it on document.ready, but alas...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using $(selector, context) iframe_response is not in the context of #iframe.

Comment: when I use `$('#iframe_response',parent)` it doesn't work either.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114243/retrieving-a-documents-parent-iframe-in-jquery/36445098#36445098

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer! It's just a little confusing to start with but really easy!

Assuming that same [origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is not a problem, you can use parent.document to access the elements, and manipulate them.

Demo: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/4PJcR/show/) 
Iframe Outer: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/4PJcR/) 
Iframe Inner: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/KwFxH/)

Hope this helps, Spent I fair bit of time figuring this out for you so I'd love the support of upping my answer!

Cheers, 
Shannon

Comment: I have changed my answer, created detailed fiddle's, this does work! take a look!

Comment: When I go to the Demo link, the box is immediately red, probably because the CSS is wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide your answer here, not in external links

Answer (score 11):

use `parent.document` instead of `window.parent.document`

```
$(parent.document).find('#whatever')
```

Comment: Hi, and do you know how to do if I don't have an ID ?

Comment: You can use any CSS selector supported by jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and none of the above solutions (jquery) did work for me.

After a little bit of trial and error this worked for me:

(But beware, this will only work if parent also supports Jquery)

```
window.parent.$('#iframe_response').html('this should go there but it\'s not...');
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
$(window.parent).find('#iframe_response').html('this should go there but it\'s not...');
```