# Is it possible to change javascript variable via iframe ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change javascript variable when iframing that page. Not the same, but did some similar on pinterest

```
if (top != self) {
$('body').html('<h1>Unauthorized</h1>')
}
```

Above is their code. I used this to cancel it

```
<iframe src="http://www.pinterest.com/?v=
if(top!%3Dself)%7B%24('body').html('%3Ch1%3EUna uthorized%3C%2Fh1%3E')%7D">
```

This works on chrome. So my question is, ccan we change javascript variables via iframe ?

Comment: same origin policy is something you should be aware: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy  So, to answer your question, you cannot

Answer (score 2):

You can use window.parent.document but beware of cross-domain operations! Have look at this link for more info: [how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice)

Comment: Thanks but why beware cross-dmoain ?