# Is it possible to check for the id of the parent iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Let's say that I've got a page in an iframe.

So...

```
top page {
iframed page{
}
}
```

Now, I want to give the iframe page an id.

From within the code on the iframed page, can I check to see if the value of the id of the iframed page is equal to something?

```
if ($('#iframeid', window.parent.document))
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can only do it if they're in the same domain.

Comment: content in iframes can't reach out to affect its enclosing page(s). it'd be a pretty bad security issue if they could.

Comment: They are on the same domain.

Comment: what you have is correct (for same domain) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice

Answer (score 0):

If it's Chrome or Firefox, you should be able to do:

```
 window.frameElement.id
```

inside the iframe to get the id of the iframe itself.

Comment: why only Chrome of Firefox?

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frameElement Opera and Safari may not support it.  Apparently IE does support it though, didn't notice that (most likely because I dont care about IE)