# JavaScript in iFrame modify objects out of the iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with an iFrame embeded. Now I want to modify a object (for example a Button) outside this iFrame by clicking on a button inside the iFrame (with Javascript).
How does this work? Can I just do it like usual?

Comment: the parent frame is accessible using `window.parent`, so, you should be able to do it like usual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-access-iframe-parent-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the parent window using window.parent. From that point, you should be able to do it like usual.

Example :
$('#yourButtonId', window.parent.document).

See also [how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice) as the question has already been asked