# accessing iframe elements from rails 3 partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe

I am trying to access iframe dom elements from rails 3 partial but its not as expected.

I am trying to access the iframe like this

```
$j("#batch_grid_frame").contents().find('#ship_box_id').html("HTML")
```

When i access the page from application it does not update the DOM. But when i run the same below code in browser console this works.

**`$j("#batch_grid_frame").contents().find('#ship_box_id').html("HTML")`**

After i googled and tried various things, this is working but is there some way in Jquery i can get this to work

```
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('batch_grid_frame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

innerDoc.getElementById("shipyu_ox_id").innerHTML = "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'elements/box_select', :locals => {:ywo_types => @ywo_types}) %>";
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It should work the same unless **iframe** is not loaded when your partial loads

Comment: its loaded. but not updating the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what helped me resolve the issue was the below answer [how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-access-iframe-parent-page-using-jquery).

I updated my code to

```
$j("#batch_grid_frame",window.parent.document).contents().find('#ship_box_id').html("HTML")
```

and it worked. Thanks.